# iOS Swift - Google Place API (Web) returns JSON in a strange format

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, google-places-api

I'm building an iOS app in Swift 3 and I'm using Google Places API to get places data. I'm using the iOS API to get most of the data I need. But I also need to get the opening times which aren't (yet) provided by the iOS API.

So I have to query the web API to get that information. The request side of things is working fine, however, once I get the result and I turn it into JSON with `JSONSerialisation`and then print the output in the console, the format of this JSON is strange and I'm struggling to parse it.

When I paste that into a JSON reader it says it's invalid.

**Here is the JSON that looks strange to me with these "(" and "=":**

```
["html_attributions": <__NSArray0 0x17001ccf0>(

)
, "result": {
    "address_components" =     (
                {
            "long_name" = 611;
            "short_name" = 611;
            types =             (
                "street_number"
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "Post Street";
            "short_name" = "Post St";
            types =             (
                route
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "Lower Nob Hill";
            "short_name" = "Lower Nob Hill";
            types =             (
                neighborhood,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "San Francisco";
            "short_name" = SF;
            types =             (
                locality,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "San Francisco County";
            "short_name" = "San Francisco County";
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = California;
            "short_name" = CA;
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "United States";
            "short_name" = US;
            types =             (
                country,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = 94109;
            "short_name" = 94109;
            types =             (
                "postal_code"
            );
        }
    );
    "adr_address" = "<span class=\"street-address\">611 Post St</span>, <span class=\"locality\">San Francisco</span>, <span class=\"region\">CA</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">94109</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">USA</span>";
    "formatted_address" = "611 Post St, San Francisco, CA 94109, USA";
    "formatted_phone_number" = "(415) 817-1391";
    geometry =     {
        location =         {
            lat = "37.7877411";
            lng = "-122.4120067";
        };
        viewport =         {
            northeast =             {
                lat = "37.78791149999999";
                lng = "-122.4119977";
            };
            southwest =             {
                lat = "37.7876843";
                lng = "-122.4120337";
            };
        };
    };
    icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png";
    id = 6a6d8b640d5260886eac5ce1b3aa73b3b0d0bb1c;
    "international_phone_number" = "+1 415-817-1391";
    name = "Joy's Place";
    "opening_hours" =     {
        "open_now" = 1;
        periods =         (
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 1;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 0;
                    time = 0800;
                };
            },
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 2;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 1;
                    time = 0700;
                };
            },
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 3;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 2;
                    time = 0700;
                };
            },
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 4;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 3;
                    time = 0700;
                };
            },
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 5;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 4;
                    time = 0700;
                };
            },
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 6;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 5;
                    time = 0700;
                };
            },
                        {
                close =                 {
                    day = 0;
                    time = 0000;
                };
                open =                 {
                    day = 6;
                    time = 0800;
                };
            }
        );
        "weekday_text" =         (
            "Monday: 7:00 am \U2013 12:00 am",
            "Tuesday: 7:00 am \U2013 12:00 am",
            "Wednesday: 7:00 am \U2013 12:00 am",
            "Thursday: 7:00 am \U2013 12:00 am",
            "Friday: 7:00 am \U2013 12:00 am",
            "Saturday: 8:00 am \U2013 12:00 am",
            "Sunday: 8:00 am \U2013 12:00 am"
        );
    };
    photos =     (
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109383364523945736298/photos\">Kathleen S</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAFE8a_M5quVcX6frenilHEFVXTycrrhj5R3MoS5sd_vKG1Gj46aJVAvVl_a4HVcPS4G5Z2JS00Pugdegn4is9KSfwIw6IoMNBL1zo3hK2dQjfArUezH9wfSYpNJCNzi4bUO6EesC4bT74B1-hzM6Us4gzKpLLAfImaF3VTeRX-SGEhCLAqUUWZsgueYvTkx8mEi8GhRCDxXbJR-ddaQFwJizvZIKa4EYKA";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109935156740971751576/photos\">Jake Lim</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAANPkBrIvYxn3UrYliLvLgk3Z4tOmS_twOv9nbMSTFmAR00Mff8XCMWQRUeigOYw1dSheyerBgimteHAHdRMzTCAWkJ7V2yB0eBS5HBewcw2yKmGHrCuCxZDdBlovGzJrwhfo5cAUB0lFDIfAXfDGnNWifD8OmLdfEzsZt97peyIrEhC84xqRQnlK32XjZkXE5huQGhQiPI0EjQ284RkMqiYxwnoHVpXOMg";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 2048;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111937150500795140908/photos\">Hope Lynch</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAFMi1hIXlNKawhA7RPl9Oah4OS6ZZyNnBRpgkHtT5gCC0brwkl55azVyulgOLsYeBkz7lpDgrpW4_9A2vg6Dtcg1bf3vVYVb1PbvADXJAV8yNwmRu9xvfSaPlgl3ty7WKW2tl8Znv8pnTMtOxfYBiTqLuFpLiEdt03pmqQMtrTKSEhADBNOSal9jDonQAMac7ghIGhTkHYMlxquEKYBuKNlbJxYY2sMmxQ";
            width = 1536;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100358998671099081635/photos\">\Uc784\Uc77c\Uc8fc</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAClp7S-w50auLq1Rtet0Glz5UjwWmSFGWKsceURE2ydHve0hFYZqf-OewYNm7xqRBA_Vdtl-nNSIgHawN5JCfyXW48fMRFi7L1mYiycxPjpZSwcH8VlQUisS1dEURkbSaY7lBH1niz197x0hhK0eTIdaPjsXboXcij7xQm6bsYSYEhDt416My2DDwuNUg7MWDrzDGhTIxwfK1eBLCjzto2X_10Ed9pvsyQ";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 5312;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113957702965980710581/photos\">Tim Lee</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAANNU12JQOxIa6Y4MBHzNedo42kZmStvSbw_JF-lhdCOtj7QoiuwfWvj1MjECq29AO7CM3QFeJiQQn3cV3GWilWHoI0EDXBodlGRe3MAG6tNhBnKBYB_jNuM_muu2o1ngWmsOXP6cmcuZmxK1z5w5cDX_aUrpli4vkKRkNuqIdbc_EhACCVmjsS6GxgLanF9s9KrVGhSEL_DpaNArYwocJzkX688WFLsEUQ";
            width = 2988;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109383364523945736298/photos\">Kathleen S</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAK8OjkKwRH84A_OKMhCXVemX8vxLS8nCp7c30JOvt7SiqGL5_XQCKz03ZiH-Tq2sshn_UBKttz3oyDJIhfAT2VTuDZgnbAPCSlNQUoP80yeATWPJJFcjJ4XxsKcQHF6Y5IDFzszEIAJYhMBQJ9I6RKMaBGMlRftIZeAEkFhN5AEtEhAozH6UEf-m0XthHPES1ldPGhTB3-JgPzRJ8aDX-B5_SyW2vs4E8Q";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114832380918896847951/photos\">Deby Lepage</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAJyut1B1yUQD6mq1FD8gQVNKo16sS6-xbnGeSs8jDtb3C5oF_oUcoUGpLTnQpHqxHfsFh7oL7cBud_h-h0xc2fhNuIkMBFQEWeZhCrmoqph5U79sH98jtOKJgjxs6i0W3-cyDlyURIux8oBfB3QzNhLqeHapJ_WFAMai74Z5ufo1EhDlCT1tkYirOAlgg18i1MVEGhQ_StyBaN3neLaiKNN2s-cTFEPz1w";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114832380918896847951/photos\">Deby Lepage</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAJ-OEm5p7FZZFsPIUBBlB-v5uPhGz3K_j9qD4fIF7lUTFUW3I_-O9gy_MZCUkD5XlZJXa2F9kfZ4Ru-Eb989IYc6YQzc3i_N3ozUOyuPhL2FDUqqkl-pltfNJJBoSOlDp4M4Ay9yrKQP6BpUP8i9P9L0gDgv-ycKDIWNh-vUDmtwEhA6F3RmxZ_tsbE131S_RcYoGhTOQTkUt1Zm9b8qUD7yxiWTjemxxQ";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109383364523945736298/photos\">Kathleen S</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAANkAGV7dv_jVNv_mGmJ9ilcPKJ9Vx24Fs1MEwy0Ce6B6hoGZ-8I0pbFVjS99TicGo3zGdi6eUbpEm76C5XplnnkuM4HGWLN1PkzHk98vVeY4hJRGY1o2qnoLaf6DnvPBmhpbrucCJK9WCNRH3-q1UZ6lzFwgxEwFAxbf-KSwJRqkEhD2Si7TWKZNQcb7bXy29QaVGhR7Yk3dOMasHvsoNwa9y-FMxzNV4w";
            width = 4032;
        },
                {
            height = 3024;
            "html_attributions" =             (
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114832380918896847951/photos\">Deby Lepage</a>"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAABqKoM9Is_KWHUlzFyDIAOh41GwUaOqPC5EwWqB_uwDTRsB4XbOksl4qylHlSbTuXpRrUUaAETi-I0coY8KyLtS5E6NxcM4f93iMl6kgsb8apJRGziedKV99EUNcdeaTWmWJOuxirP_7wwiadwUiwbmfjZ05e2EkAtfmjCb8vHTYEhDsAfUeyhcyQu_riR-Vrd9JGhRwlTegpWWdYn9uVGVhs02SjIyXsQ";
            width = 4032;
        }
    );
    "place_id" = "ChIJheCrEY6AhYARxCkT8_KjDWE";
    rating = "4.4";
    reference = "CmRRAAAAeYm_xV5gsn_eVlrvpkEolaqaHFO0CWS5rWXJ5z5QWX8ReJKLPl6eDnvFM0PD2BNMkgfui9Z42_jmUxCIeTeZi3OEaod73XuU_rzLpRAdlOm8IcTaLX6YeYJeS4qFqZxLEhBUzZmWo-SU9WY4YG8WP8GOGhSwAPbhHWRuZh0X6wC1LMD3Los44A";
    reviews =     (
                {
            aspects =             (
                                {
                    rating = 2;
                    type = overall;
                }
            );
            "author_name" = "Lanxin Chu";
            "author_url" = "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/117750042826931398790/reviews";
            language = en;
            rating = 4;
            "relative_time_description" = "5 months ago";
            text = "Red bean shaved ice was good and definitely did not skimp out on ingredients! Green tea latte was solid. Ambiance was pretty nice. There were a lot of people studying there; as noted by others this makes for somewhat limited seating sometimes so keep that in mind.";
            time = 1470610849;
        },
                {
            aspects =             (
                                {
                    rating = 3;
                    type = overall;
                }
            );
            "author_name" = "Esther Gibbs";
            "author_url" = "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/110692487628239988503/reviews";
            language = en;
            rating = 5;
            "relative_time_description" = "a month ago";
            text = "Delicious food and drink- especially their sweet potato latte! Fairtrade and organic everything and a lovely working environment";
            time = 1479462640;
        },
                {
            aspects =             (
                                {
                    rating = 2;
                    type = overall;
                }
            );
            "author_name" = "Johnny Wang";
            "author_url" = "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103379264202553362035/reviews";
            language = en;
            "profile_photo_url" = "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-EtpIyKVUteI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAA4c/riPrz4_6j-s/photo.jpg";
            rating = 4;
            "relative_time_description" = "7 months ago";
            text = "It's been called to my attention that I never reviewed this place, despite the number of times I've visited, which is... surprising. Honestly though, there's not too much to say: I've only ever come here for the patbingsoo, which is massively generous in portion size, and fantastically delicious in flavor, and definitely ideal for sharing. But hey, everything can be a personal serving if you try hard enough.\n\nAs for the place itself, it's a nice, chill little cafe that's been packed every single time I go, so seating can be a little hard to find at times. You'll usually find it occupied by folks busy working away on their laptops.\n\n***Accessibility Info***\n\nVenue - On the smaller side, as far as cafes/coffee shops go, with about 2/3 of the seating being accessible: those along the walls were bench seating, and there's lower coffee table seating towards the right as well, leaving only the middle aisle and outer seats along the sides accessible.\n\nBathroom - Didn't try them.";
            time = 1465162538;
        },
                {
            aspects =             (
                                {
                    rating = 2;
                    type = overall;
                }
            );
            "author_name" = "Victor Vu";
            "author_url" = "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/108347888656400683025/reviews";
            language = en;
            "profile_photo_url" = "//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-92ZhOOjfwfE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAZqA/16j_bEwt6fk/photo.jpg";
            rating = 4;
            "relative_time_description" = "7 months ago";
            text = "Great place to study... when it's quiet. There's enough light to clearly see your paperwork. Music is on the medium side and easy to phase out when you put on headphones, or focus really hard. It's really chill!\n\nFood and drinks are nice. It's a great place for coffee and deserts. Most people get waffles or ice cream here. Their matcha green tea is nice as well.\n\nThe only problem is that there is never enough seating during peak hours and it gets claustrophobic when it's crowded with people doing their homework.\n\nSeats are also cheap and hurt your butt.\n\nThis place usually attracts the Asian crowd.";
            time = 1463551785;
        },
                {
            aspects =             (
                                {
                    rating = 1;
                    type = overall;
                }
            );
            "author_name" = "Brian Melton";
            "author_url" = "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103909645378067844462/reviews";
            language = en;
            "profile_photo_url" = "//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-enGmeXKqYC0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAA4eo/maQQGZ8Etdo/photo.jpg";
            rating = 3;
            "relative_time_description" = "a month ago";
            text = "Expensive, small-sized coffees make this coffee shop feel like poor value-for-money. Limited food options but has great desserts: try the macaroons.";
            time = 1480554027;
        }
    );
    scope = GOOGLE;
    types =     (
        cafe,
        restaurant,
        food,
        store,
        "point_of_interest",
        establishment
    );
    url = "https://maps.google.com/?cid=6993426060231780804";
    "utc_offset" = "-480";
    vicinity = "611 Post Street, San Francisco";
    website = "http://www.joysplacecafe.com/";
}, "status": OK]
```

**And here is my code with a dummy query:**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJheCrEY6AhYARxCkT8_KjDWE&key=[MYAPIKEY]")

let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }

    do {
        guard let placeData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            as? [String: Any] else {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
        }

        print("The placeData is: \(placeData.description)")

        guard let website = placeData["website"] as? String else {
            print("Could not get the website from JSON")
            return
        }
        print("The title is: \(website)")
    } catch  {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Any help understanding what's going on would be much appreciated. The final objective is to get the Opening hours a Dictionary with the keys being the days of the week and the values being the opening times.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Eric, looks like I was indeed confused. Will look into that. I'm new to this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `reponseData` is a dictionary with a key `response` containing the actual dictionary you want. The JSON looks something like:

```
{
    "result": {
        "website": "example.com"
    }
}
```

So the correct code would be:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJheCrEY6AhYARxCkT8_KjDWE&key=[MYAPIKEY]")

let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }

    do {
        guard let placeData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            as? [String: Any] else {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
        }

        print("The placeData is: \(placeData.description)")

        guard let website = (placeData["result"] as? [String : Any])?["website"] as? String else {
            print("Could not get the website from JSON")
            return
        }
        print("The title is: \(website)")
    } catch  {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I simply changed:

`guard let website = placeData["website"] as? String else {`

to:

`guard let website = (placeData["result"] as? [String : Any])?["website"] as? String else {`

Comment: Thanks Coder256 ! Bit confusing as it was the first time I was doing that. I've tried with you code sample and I got what I wanted.